# Why should I use the R.id, as opposed to the code it generates?

Tags: android, optimization

I mean, besides code cleanliness, is it a preference, or a taboo? I'm just curious.

For instance:

```
public static final class layout {
public static final int main=0x7f030000;
```

why not use "0x7f030000" instead of "R.id.main"?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on  what "the code it generates" is

Comment: So you want to remember the long integer value that is generated automatically instead of the name that you gave the `View`? If I understand you correctly

Comment: I don't mind using long random strings of numbers, that's cake. It doesn't bother me. @ianhanniballake hit it on the nose. The numbers may change, hence using the static number would avoid errors.

Comment: @codeMagic I obviously have a problem. My brain just likes that kind of stuff. I'd prefer it that way. So BEFORE I went on to do it I wanted to make sure, and I found a lot of ambiguity on the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IDs generated in R.id are **not** static. Any additional IDs you add to any of your XML files may change previously generated values. Therefore you should always use R.id.your_id as those **are** static.

Comment: In addition, it's FAR more convenient to use a textual representation of the ID of an object than a long hexadecimal number.

Comment: Agreed with @Raceimaztion. Let's see if you remember what `0x7f030000` represents after you've been away from the project for two weeks.